# Why/How can you make a parameter optional if the return type depends on it?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

There's this part in Tour of Heroes where they make the result parameter optional, but then they use the `of` RxJS function to mock the result type in the return statement:

```
private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

    // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
    console.error(error); // log to console instead

    // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
    this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

    // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
    return of(result as T);
  };
}
```

Source: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#handleerror

Why is this a thing? If there is no result, won't this end up throwing an error? Why is it optional?

Comment: Actually it won't crash. If you don't provide value to the functions it equals to undefined. it's still a value so you loose nothing.

Comment: If there's no result, you'll get an observable of undefined. The generic type is only used at compile time.

Comment: but if its always us who call handleError, and we will always call it by piping an observable then why is it customary to make the result parameter optional? Is there a case where I would want handleError to return an observable of undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to worry about having no type to assign to `T`, because if you do not pass `result` to `handleError`, `T` will be `undefined` by default. Undefined is besides a value also its own type.

---

An interesting thing to note is that `handleError` does not actually create the observable itself, but instead returns a function that will do that everytime you call it.

```js
private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {

    // This function is returned:
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
        log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
        return of(result as T);
    };
}
```

So if we call `handleError` with an `operation` we get back a function that we can repeatedly call with errors, and it will re-use the name/description for each call. It's simply a way to normalise error handling with a plain function. Now the `result` being optional starts to make a lot more sense. Consider:

```js
const handler = this.handleError('Fetching stuff');

const err1 = new Error('something went wrong');
const err2 = new Error('something else went wrong');

handler(err1); // "Fetching stuff failed: something went wrong"
handler(err2); // "Fetching stuff failed: something else went wrong"
```

Similarly we can pass a `result` value to `handleError` that will be re-used for all calls to the returned function. I think this is most useful when the functions returned from `handleError` are used outside of the class they're created in. That way you expose a function that returns observables of a fixed value that is known by the class, possibly to inform the calling code of additional information after handling the error.

---

**Update**

Looking at [the next snippet](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#tap-into-the-observable) at the link you provided we can see how `handleError` is actually used:

```js
 /** GET heroes from the server */
 getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
     return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
         .pipe(
             tap(_ => this.log('fetched heroes')),
             catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
         );
 }
```

It shows that it is used as error handler for failed http requests. `result` is an empty array that acts as default value for the array of heroes (`Hero[]`) that `getHeroes` promises to return.

Used in this way this is a [currying technique](https://javascript.info/currying-partials) that plays nicely with the observable `catchError` operator. The operator re-uses the returned error handler, and will call it with any error that might occur.